# Receiving events from parent component inside child component projected via ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-content-projection

Consider this simplified situation, we have:

Parent component template (selector: 'parent'):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input (blur)="onBlur()"/>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Child component template (selector: 'child'):

```
<div>{{ valueEmittedFromParentInputOnBlurEvent }}</div>
```

Usage, somewhere on a page:

```
<parent>
  <child></child>
</parent>
```

I'd like to handle `valueEmittedFromParentInputOnBlurEvent` in my `child` component after it was emitted in onBlur() event.
Please, help me if you can :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service or provide an Input to your Child Component.

Comment: Yep, but I'd like to don't use it in direct relations child-parent, I suspect there should be a more simple way which I don't know at the moment )

Answer (score 0):

Follow this concept to have communication between parent and child:

1. In your html parent component:

```
<child #child></child>
<input (blur)="child.onBlurEvent()"/>
```

you define your child component as #child to access its methods like onBlurEvent()

2. In your ts child component

```
number = 0;
onBlurMethod() {
    this.number++;
}
```

3. In your html child component

```
<h1>{{number}}</h1>
```

when onBlur event occurs in your parent it will call onBlurEvent method in child and the method will do whatever it must do

this was an example to help you to understand about parent and child communication, this concept will help you to solve your problem, good luck

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for ng-content. I can't refer to `onBlurEvent()` method of unknown at the moment child :(
I meant this
```
<ng-content #child></ng-content>
<input (blur)="child.onBlurEvent()"/>
```
doesn't work.